# What is Difference Between Laravel Listener's handle function and constructor function?

Tags: laravel, events, listener

When Listener is triggered from event sometime it renders to __construct() function and sometimes it renders to handle() function. I am confused what are the conditions to rendering on _construct() and handle() functions.
I am calling event

```
event(new OnForbiddenUserFound(CommonUtil::fetch($request, 'identity_number'),CommonUtil::fetch($request, 'identity_type'), CommonUtil::fetch($request, 'purpose', 'forbidden_users.purpose.general')));
```

my service provider is

```
protected $listen = [
        OnForbiddenUserFound::class => [
            AddForbiddenUser::class
        ],
    ];
```

my event is

```
class OnForbiddenUserFound
{
    use SerializesModels;

    public $identityNumber, $identityType, $purpose;

    public function __construct($identityNumber, $identityType, $purpose)
    {
        $this->identityNumber = $identityNumber;
        $this->identityType = $identityType;
        $this->purpose = $purpose;
    }
}
```

and listener is

```
class AddForbiddenUser
{

  public function __construct(){
    dd("construct");
  }

  public function handle(OnForbiddenUserFound $event)
  {
    $identityNumber = $event->identityNumber;
    $identityType = $event->identityType;
    $purpose = $event->purpose;
    dd("handle");
 }
}
```

So when event is called, it goes to constructor rather than handle function. why is that?

Answer (score 0):

Constructor is a `PHP` / `OOD` internal function that is called when object is instantiated. Imagine the following constructor.

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->title = 'always';
}
```

On an object with such a constructor, the object can not exist without the title always, as the constructor is always invoked on a new creation of the object. There should not be put flow state logic in constructor, it is only for instantiating the object with values.

The handle method, is simply a `Laravel` approach to encapsulate logic that is invoked in the context it is used. Somewhere `Laravel` will invoke your object similar to this (most certainly a little more generic than this example).

```
(new AddForbiddenUser)->handle();
```